# Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity?

Tags: sftp, filezilla

Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity?
Error:       File transfer failed after transferring 6,094,848 bytes in 190 second

Comment: This happens on the internet sometimes.  This question is off-topic.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 30):

Open FileZilla->Edit->Setting->Timeout in Seconds: - 20 ->change to ->500.